# MongoDB data directory on remote server

Tags: mongodb, storage

I was wondering if there is any way to have separate servers for engine and storage of MongoDB? I am interested in running the MongoDB engine on a local Ubuntu machine but store the data remotely on another server, like having a remote address for MongoDB data directory.

Comment: Just look at the parameters available when starting `mongod`, specifically `--dbpath`. That is the option you have.

Comment: can you have it point to an external server?